# Loop on the value in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to loop in Angular2 on some value, using code something like this:

```
if (true) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        console.log("the value of i is : " + i); 
    }
} else {
    console.log("in else part") ; 
}
```

In the console, I can see the value for `i` is always `0`, so I'm pretty sure this is not the correct way to loop in Angular 2.

I even tried using:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
    console.log("value : " + i) ; 
}
```

But the result is the same.

Can anyone please show me how do we loop/iterate in Angular 2?

Comment: When you say "something like this", what you've posted is not the actual code? Have you run what's posted?

Comment: It seems to be working here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/054IzS2loIsHjL6CKcqy?p=preview

Comment: When you use `let` the variable is scoped to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `i` variable outside the `for` block scope.

```
let i: number;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  console.log("value : " + i) ; 
}
```

Comment: Which is similar to using `for (var...`

Answer (score 0):

when you use the typescript, the main is the type declaration. So, I think you must declare the type of i.
that is,

```
let i: number;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log("value: " + i);
}
```

That's all.